# How can i make a usercontrol(ascx) grid selection enable and disable at multiple pages(aspx)?

Tags: c#

I have a user control with a grid. i am using this user control at multiple aspx pages. i only need to enable the grid selection in one of the page and at rest of pages in need to disable the grid selection.

How can i make this usercontrol grid selection enable and disable at multiple pages?

Comment: Do you mean that you want selection enabled on one page, but only that one page?

Answer (score 1):

Have the grid selection disabled by default.

Create a property in your user control:

```
public bool AllowGridSelection
{
    set
    {
        if (value)
            //enable the grid here
    }
}
```

Then set that property from the code-behind of the page that needs selection enabled:

```
MyUserControl.AllowGridSelection = true;
```